# Missing Subscribing messages publish by Qos=2

Tags: python, mqtt

I am subscribing message on Topic "OK/Topic" for Qos=2 but sometime i didn't get message publish by Qos=2 , Following my code of Subscribing :

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("OK/Topic",2)

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(" Topic : "+str(msg.topic)+"  and Message is : "+str(msg.payload))

def on_subscribe(client, userdata,mid, granted_qos):
    print "userdata : " +str(userdata)


strs="my-message-to-publish"
mqttc = mqtt.Client("Python-MQTT-Pub-Sub")
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
mqttc.connect("IP", PORT, 60)
mqttc.start_loop()
while True:
    mqttc.publish("New/Topic",str(strs))
    print "publish message " + str(strs)
    time.sleep(1)
```

And my publisher code on Topic "OK/Topic" is as follows :

```
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    client.disconnect()

mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.on_publish = on_publish
mqttc.publish("OK/Topic","my_message",2)
```

If i publish 10 message i would recieve on Subscriber 7-8 message but not 10
anyone knows why i am missing some messages.

Thanks ..!!!

Answer (score 1):

Calling disconnect in the in the on_publish method is most likely closing the connection before the full QOS2 process can finish cleanly.

Instead of using publish and on_publish to disconnect try using the single method to do the full connect, publish, cleanup in one synchronous method:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single(topic, payload=None, qos=0, retain=False, hostname="localhost", port=1883, client_id="", keepalive=60, will=None, auth=None, tls=None,protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
```

Comment: Thanks hardlib..!!  I  tried  with above  single method by changing protocol version  "protocol=mqtt.MQTTv31"  because my mosquitto is an MQTT v3.1 broker, But same  i am missing some publish messages.  any clue ..

Comment: On client mosquitto_sub -t 'OK/Topic' i see all publish messages gathering on broker side but Subscriber is not subscribing all messages...